# Rules for inequalities: possible errata in Calculus book

Tags: calculus

I've just started to learn calculus reading the book "[Cálculo](https://www.amazon.es/C%C3%A1lculo-Robert-Adams/dp/8478290893/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=calculo%20amdas&qid=1602740392&sr=8-1-fkmr0)" by Robert Adams. Its fifth rule is.

If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, then:

$$a > b \Rightarrow {\frac 1 a} > 0$$

But if $a = 0$ and $b = -1$, then we get ${\frac 1 0} > 0$. but $\frac{1}{0}$ is not defined.

Is the above true or is it an errata?

Comment: $\frac10$ is not $\infty$, but that's beside the point. What are the restrictions on $b$ and $a$, if any? $-1 > -2$ but $\frac1{-1} < 0$.

Comment: $-1>-2$ but $\frac{1}{-1}>0$ is wrong

Comment: The truth is that I don't know what you mean by that. I repeat "I've just started to learn Calculus". Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel What are the given conditions on $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @user $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

Comment: there has to be a restriction on $a$ or $b$ or both. If there isn't, then you will get something undefined and ambiguous like $\frac{1}{0}>0$.

Comment: Please tell why you have downvoting my question. It is a good question and a doubt I have reading a book with 7 editions.

Comment: Maybe you don't know the inequalities rules, this is why you don't vote me. Please, tell me. What I did wrong? Why this questions is not good? I have found an errata in a book.

Comment: @Peter there is an errata in the book that I'm reading. Check my own answer for this question.

Comment: I edited the question and removed my downvote.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. There is an errata in its [Spanish version](https://www.amazon.es/C%C3%A1lculo-Robert-Adams/dp/8478290893/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=calculo%20amdas&qid=1602740392&sr=8-1-fkmr0), 6th edition. You don't need to downvoting me if I found an errata in a book.

Checking the same book but on its [ninth edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134154363) in English, and the fifth rule is:

$$a > 0 \Rightarrow {\frac 1 a} > 0$$

I repeat:

> You don't need to downvoting me if I found an errata in a book.

Comment: Again, the downvotes are (at least mine) not for the wrong rule, but for the wrong formulation of the counterexample. Things like $\frac{1}{0}$ should be avoided. At least we know now that it was just a typo corrected in a later version.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found [an online pdf](http://eng.usc.ac.ir/files/1508848447251.pdf) of the book you're talking about.

It doesn't have that as its fifth rule; the fifth rule states

[image]

which is true; divide both sides by $a^2$ and you get the result ($a^2$ will always be positive, so the sign doesn't change, but it doesn't even matter because $a$ is positive as per the rule).

Comment: Slight remark : We need $a\ne 0$ so that we can divide by $a^2$, but because of $a>0$ this is certain. In particular, we cannot arrive at the undefined "$\frac{1}{0}$". We can also argue that the fraction of positive real numbers is positive.

Comment: @VansFannel Why are you getting so defensive? I didn't accuse you of doing anything. How am I supposed to know that you are using a Spanish version of the textbook when your original question didn't state that, nor did it even state the page number that this so-called "rule" was on? You should be thanking me for actually taking the time to find your textbook on the internet and find the "rule" myself (with no page number given!) so that you could realize that your textbook did have an error in it.

Answer (score 0):

$$a>b\implies \frac1a>0$$ is plain wrong.

Then

$$\frac10,\infty$$ are not numbers and you cannot use them in relational expressions.